# Lucene Hightlighter text limitation

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

In reference to this issue:-
[Lucene Hightlighter sometimes inexplicably returns blank fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726171/lucene-hightlighter-sometimes-inexplicably-returns-blank-fragments)

Can someone tell me what the best approach would be if I have very large documents to analyze?

I'm guessing the MaxDocCharsToAnalyze property can be set to Int32.MaxValue which is currently 2147483647.

What happens if I need to analyze text which is more than this?

Comment: Well... you could always reimplement the [`Highlighter`](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/contrib/Highlighter/Highlighter.cs) class while stripping the `_maxDocCharsToAnalyze`-related code, but I guess you'd blow up the RAM doing so. Do you *really* need to highlight a >2GB document *in one shot*?

Comment: I'm not very sure about the amount of space each character occupies? Are you assuming each character uses 1 byte of space?